# Restrict access to Tomcat manager by IP

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat-valve, tomcat-manager

I'm trying to restrict all the requests to my Tomcat manager which don't come from my IP.

So far, I found that adding a Valve to the server.xml like this:

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="IP"/>
```

will block all requests except the ones coming from "IP" to the whole Tomcat (including the webapps). Does anyone know how to do the same but applying only to the Tomcat manager?

By the way, I'm using Tomcat7.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In `[tomcat]/conf/Catalina/[hostname]` create a file `manager.xml`.

So if your hostname is `www.yourdomainname.com` and tomcat is in `opt/tomcat7/` that would be:

```
/opt/tomcat7/conf/Catalina/www.yourdomainname.com/manager.xml
```

In this newly created `manager.xml`  you put the `RemoteAddrValve` in the Context:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">

   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" 
    allow="127\.0\.0\.1|11\.22\.33\.44" denyStatus="404" />

</Context>
```

Separate multiple ip adresses by a pipe character.

I choose `denyStatus=404` so possible trespassers wont have a clue there even exists a manager.

Restart Tomcat.

---

**UPDATE 3/2020**

If Tomcat sits behind a proxy server, requests will all be coming from that proxy server, so you need to tell the proxy server to forward remote addresses to Tomcat (in Nginx you would include a line `proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for $remote_addr;`).

In addition you need to tell Tomcat to watch for that forwarded header by including a `RemoteIpValve` in either an Engine or a Host block:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
        remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For" 
        requestAttributesEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: works perfect! also great addition to deny the status!

Comment: I just tried this with Tomcat 7.0.64 and 8.0.36 without restarting and they worked.

Comment: how to test this?

Comment: @PeakGen You could request the manager with a browser from an ipaddress not in the allow list. It should show the 404.

Answer (score 7):

In Tomcat8 I found the RemoteAddrValve already in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager\META-INF\context.xml`, and I just needed to uncomment it...

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!--
    Remove the comment markers from around the Valve below to limit access to
    the manager application to clients connecting from localhost
  -->

  <!--<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />-->

</Context>
```

I added @acdhirr's suggestion to the valve to deny the status `denyStatus="404"`, and that worked also.